# Xstream nested Array Issue

Tags: xml, xstream

I have XML structure as below

```
<PaymentData>
  <reserveData>
     <reserveDto>
        <pNumber>
     </reserveDto>
  </reserveData>
</PaymentData>
```

and My class structure is as below

```
Class PaymentData                                             
   Private ReserveData reserveData                    
Class ReserveData (Xtream alias “reserveData”)        
  Private ReserveDto lReserveDto[];                   
Class ReserveDto  (Xtream alias “reserveDto”)
  Private String pNumber
```

When I have above structure and Xtream.fromXML() doesn't generate values to the ReserveData.

I know there is alternative solution by using Xstream Implicit and ArrayList as below

```
Class PaymentData                                             
   Private ReserveData reserveData                    
Class ReserveData      
  @XStreamImplicit
  ArrayList<ReserveDto> reserveDto                  
Class ReserveDto 
  Private String pNumber
```

But we don't want to change to ArrayList as client has limitation to use only array.
Please let me know if any one has solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XStream Annotations Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html) suggests that you can use `@XStreamImplicit` on arrays (and maps) as well as lists.

Comment: Thanks. We were using Xstream version jar 1.2 which doesn't support @XStreamImplicit on arrays,After upgrading to 1.3.4 jar , issue is resolved

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider _accepting_ it by clicking the green tick mark to the left.  People will be more willing to answer your future questions if they know you are likely to accept good answers.